# How to get DIV Table headers and footers to repeat when the Div Table is broken by a page-break when printing

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-tables

I'm trying to replace a normal html table using DIVs. However, it isn't behaving as I'd expect when the table is split with a page-break when printed or rendered to a PDF. I'd assume that it would behave like a normal table, whereby the table-header repeats at the top of the page, and the table-footer at the bottom.

[Header row]

[Table rows]

---Page break---

[Header row]

[Table rows]

[Footer row]

```css
.Table {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.TableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.TableHeading {
  display: table-header-group;
  background-color: #ddd;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.TableCell,
.TableHead {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 3px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #999999;
}

.TableFoot {
  display: table-footer-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.TableBody {
  display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="Table">
  <div class="TableHeading">
    <div class="TableHead">
      Month
    </div>
    <div class="TableHead">
      Person
    </div>
    <div class="TableHead">
      Amount
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TableBody">
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        January
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Bob
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €100
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        February
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Fred
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €130
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="TableRow">
      <div class="TableCell">
        March
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        Larry
      </div>
      <div class="TableCell">
        €150
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="TableFoot">
    <div class="TableHead">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="TableHead">
      &nbsp;
    </div>
    <div class="TableHead">
      €1234
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "page break"? There are no pages in HTML. The behaviour you are describing exits in text editors like MS Word, but not in HTML.

Comment: Apologies. I meant when the page is printed or rendered to a PDF. I'll update the description.

Comment: @Tijmen Really ... that isn't necessary for normal HTML tables.

Comment: You want to add headers and footers on every page or you want to remove headers and footers from every page, please clarify.

Comment: @alj True, but that is because the browser 'knows' that an HTML table is a table. Your current set-up isn't technically a table, it's a bunch of `div` elements made to visually represent a table. Hence, the browser doesn't 'know' this is a table.

Comment: @Tijmen The '.Table {display: table;}' and all the other table attributes in the css above do that. As the accepted solution shows, it does work with Firefox and Edge out of the box, it's just Chrome and Opera that need an additional attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied your code snippets, and I found out that work as expected (repeating, that is) on Firefox & Edge, but not Chrome & Opera.
So I thought it was some kind of specific browser bug, and after some search I found this:

break-inside:avoid;

Add this CSS to .TableHeading and .TableFoot - tested it and works. But it breaks somewhat the footer's vertical alignment

The solution was found [here](http://blog.dev030.com/posts/repeating-table-headers-pdf-downloads-using-headless-chrome), with history and explanation.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for that. By default I have been using Chrome, but as you said, it works on Firefox out of the box. The other references also work which is great as we are using Puppeteer.